# How to use for in another for cycle in django

Tags: python, django

I'm building some kind of list in which we have Section and Category assigned to the section.

In my view.py it looks like this:

```
args['sections'] = ShopSection.objects.all().order_by('name')
args['categories'] =  ShopCategory.objects.all().order_by('-name')
```

And my template looks like this:

```
<div class="panel side-panel-1">
<h4 class="title1">Разделы</h4>
<ul class="clear-list">
<li class="">
        <a href="/advert/adverts.aspx">Все разделы</a>
</li>
{% for section in sections %}
    <li class="">
        <!--<a href="/advert/adverts.aspx&sec{{ section.id }}">{{ section.name }}</a>-->
        <a class="" data-dropdown="autoCloseExample" aria-controls="autoCloseExample" aria-expanded="false">
            {{ section.name }} ({{ section.shopcategory_set.count }}) {{section.shopcategory_set.id}} {{ section.id }}
        </a>
        <ul id="autoCloseExample" class="f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" aria-autoclose="false" tabindex="-1">

            {% for category in categories %}
            {% if section.id == category.section_id%}
            <li style="width: 100%;"><a href="#">{{ category.name }} sec={{section.id}} cat={{category.id}} catsec={{category.section_id}}</a></li>
            {% else %}
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The working page is [here](http://open.tm:8080/store/store.aspx).

The problem is when I use `{% if section.id == category.section_id %}` I want to filter category list according to the section id, but `section.id` is not defining properly.

For example:

- If I use `{% if section.id > 3 %}` then in cycle it defines `section.id` as `4`
- If i use `{% if section.id < 3 %}` then in cycle it defines `section.id` as `2`

what i want is

- -Section id-1
- --Category1 which has section_id-1
- --Category2 which has section_id-1
- --Category3 which has section_id-1
- -Section id-2
- --Category4 which has section_id-2
- --Category5 which has section_id-2
- --Category6 which has section_id-2

Comment: What do you mean 'is not defining properly.'? I don't understand what's wrong with your code. It should work fine.

Comment: Yes, 4 is greater than 3, and 2 is less than 3. In other words, that code does exactly what you would expect. What, precisely, is your problem?

Comment: I also think that it should work fine. But it doesn't. Simplyfied qestion is "How to use variable from main cycle in the second cycle"
{% for some in somes %}
{{ some.id}}
{% for second in seconds %}
{% if some.id == second.id %}RESULT{% endif %}
{% endfor%}
{% endfor %}

Comment: @Daniel_Roseman. The problem is that section.id must be different since it is in cycle. in which some items has id-4 and some has id-6. So the second cycle should filter query according to the item value from the first cycle

Comment: @ilyasJumadurdyew And what's wrong? It should do what you want. Please, edit question with example what you've got and what you've expect. Like you expect: `section.id = 4, category.id = 1, 3, 5`. You got: `section.id = 4, category.id = 2, 4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `ShopCategory` has a ForeignKey to `ShopSection`, the cleanest and easiest way to do so is to change your second for loop like this so you don't have to check on the `section_id`:

```
{% for category in section.shopcategory_set.all %}
    <li style="width: 100%;"><a href="#">{{ category.name }} sec={{section.id}} cat={{category.id}} catsec={{ section.id }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: No luck :-( . It still shows all the categories for all sections

Comment: Are you sure you tried this: `section.shopcategory_set.all`, it's supposed to show you all categories for this section or nothing.

Comment: Yes, I've copy/pasted your answer. And the result still the same. It shows same category list for any section

Comment: I'm trying to solve this problem for 4 hours but still no luck. the main reason or the main problem is that variable from first query is not defining correctly in the if operator of the second